# trying to populate a simple databse in tkinter with sqlite3

Tags: python, tkinter

i seriously do need help on this one, am kinda new to python and tkinter and i've trying to create something with it. when i try to insert data via an entry box. this is the error i get

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File

```
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/.../Documents/atom-python.projects/billingsystem.py", line 217, in <lambda>
    enterbutton = ttk.Button(self, text='Enter', command=lambda:(insert(self)))
  File "/Users/.../Documents/atom-python.projects/billingsystem.py", line 45, in insert
    item_i = self.entryitem.get()
AttributeError: 'inventrylog' object has no attribute 'entryitem'
```

And this is my code,

```
def Database(self):
    global conn, cursor
    conn = sqlite3.connect("billingsystem.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, item TEXT, price TEXT)")
    #cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `item` = '?' AND `price` = '?'")
    conn.commit()


def insert(self):
    item_i = self.entryitem.get()
    price_i = self.pentry.get(self)

conn = sqlite3.connect('billingsystem.db')
with conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO product(item, price ) VALUES(?,?)', (item_i, price_i))
    lis = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM product')


class billingsystem(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  # initialize class
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)  # initialize tkinter

    tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default='')
    tk.Tk.wm_title(self, 'DEPARTMENTAL BILLING SYSTEM')



    container = tk.Frame(self)  # call frame
    container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)  # pack frame
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # configure frame row
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # configure frame column
    self.frames = {}  # dictionary



    for F in (StartPage,Record,inventory,inventrylog):
        frame = F (container, self)  # defining startframe page
        self.frames[F] = frame  # put frame in ditionary
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')  # pack frame

    self.show_frame(StartPage)  # show startpage frame

def show_frame(self, cont): #defining show_frame functiion
    frame = self.frames[cont] #putting show_frame function in a dict with key [cont]
    frame.tkraise() #raising frames

    # menubar
    menubar = tk.Menu(self)
    inventory = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    inventory.add_command(label='Inventory', command=lambda:self.show_frame(inventrylog))
    inventory.add_separator()
    inventory.add_command(label='Exit', command=quit)
    menubar.add_cascade(label='Inventory Log', menu=inventory)

    tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    label1 = tk.Label(self, text=('Date:',time.strftime('%A %m/%d/%y',time.localtime())), font=LARGE_FONT)
    label1.place(x=30,y=30)


    clock = tk.Label(self, text=time_string, font=LARGE_FONT)
    clock.place(x=240, y=30)

    def tick():
        global time1
        # get the current local time from the PC
        time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        # if time string has changed, update it
        if time2 != time1:
            time1 = time2
            clock.config(text=('Time:',time2))
        # calls itself every 200 milliseconds
        # to update the time display as needed
        # could use >200 ms, but display gets jerky
        clock.after(200, tick)
    tick()


    label3 = tk.Label(self, text='Item', font=LARGE_FONT)
    label3.place(x=30,y=100)

    entry_1 = Entry(self)
    entry_1.place(x=30,y=120)

    label4 = tk.Label(self, text='Quantity', font=LARGE_FONT)
    label4.place(x=30,y=170)

    entry_2 = Entry(self)
    entry_2.place(x=30,y=190)

    calculatebutton = ttk.Button(self, text='Enter')
    calculatebutton.place(x=30, y=250)

    button4 = ttk.Button(self, text='TOTAL')
    #command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Record))
    button4.place(x=30,y=390)


    #entry_3 = Entry(self)
    #entry_3.place(x=30,y=260)


    #cmb = tk.Listbox(self)
    #cmb.place(x=250,y=120)
    chat1 = ttk.Treeview(self, height=15, columns=('Quantity','Price'), selectmode="extended")
    chat1.heading('#0', text='Item', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    chat1.heading('#1', text='Quntity', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    chat1.heading('#2', text='Price', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    chat1.column('#1', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=100)
    chat1.column('#2', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=100)
    chat1.column('#0', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=100)
    chat1.place(x=250,y=120)

    label5 = tk.Label(self, text='Total:', font=LARGE_FONT)
    label5.place(x=250, y=440)


    button1 = ttk.Button(self, text='VIEW RECORDS', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Record))
    button1.place(x=30,y=440)  # adding buttons to frame or page

class Record(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    label1 = tk.Label(self,text=('Date:',time.strftime('%A %m/%d/%y',time.localtime())), font=LARGE_FONT)
    label1.place(x=30, y=30)

    #cmb = tk.Listbox(self)
    #cmb.place(x=30, y=100)

    chat2 = ttk.Treeview(self, height=15, columns=('Quantity', 'Price'), selectmode="extended")
    chat2.heading('#0', text='Item', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    chat2.heading('#1', text='Quntity', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    chat2.heading('#2', text='Price', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    chat2.column('#1', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=160)
    chat2.column('#2', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=160)
    chat2.column('#0', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=160)
    chat2.place(x=50, y=90)

    button2 = ttk.Button(self, text='BACK TO MAIN', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    button2.place(x=30, y=440)  # adding buttons to frame or page

    button3 = ttk.Button(self, text='EXIT', command=quit)
    button3.place(x=400,y=440)



class inventrylog(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    itemlabel = tk.Label(self, text='Item', font=LARGE_FONT)
    itemlabel.place(x=30, y=100)


    entryitem = Entry(self)
    entryitem.place(x=30, y=120)

    pricelabel = tk.Label(self, text='price', font=LARGE_FONT)
    pricelabel.place(x=30, y=170)

    pentry = Entry(self)
    pentry.place(x=30, y=190)

    inventorychat = ttk.Treeview(self, height=15, columns=('Quantity', 'Price'), selectmode="extended")
    inventorychat.heading('#0', text='Item', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    inventorychat.heading('#1', text='Quntity', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    inventorychat.heading('#2', text='Price', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    inventorychat.column('#1', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=100)
    inventorychat.column('#2', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=100)
    inventorychat.column('#0', stretch=tk.YES, minwidth=50, width=100)
    inventorychat.place(x=250, y=120)

    enterbutton = ttk.Button(self, text='Enter', command=lambda:(insert(self)))
    #popupmsg('Not Supported Just Yet!'))
    enterbutton.place(x=30, y=300)  # adding buttons to frame or page
```

Need all the help i can get. thanks

Comment: the code is too much and your question is not clear , i can see you have parsed `inventorylog` as command to your `menubar` is it entry or function

Comment: yeah am just passing that inventory log to the command to load the frame. thats the part thats creating the problem. wow... i can the part of the code to which the problem is didn't appear

Comment: def insert(self):
    item_i = self.entryitem.get(self)
    price_i = self.pentry.get(self)

    conn = sqlite3.connect('billingsystem.db')
    with conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO product(item, price ) VALUES(?,?)', (item_i, price_i))
        lis = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM product') .  This is the part that's giving me hell

Comment: @ AD WAN it worked thanks a lot, i jxt had to push the insert function a few lines down.